# How to target state in react testing libary?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

Basically, the Main task is that I am having a state

const [isShow,setIsShow] = useState(false);

I just want to target the isShow state so I can get the current value of its state,
so I can test whether my component is rendered or not.

Main.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Main({
    name
}) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(0);
    const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false);
    return (
        <>
            {
                isShow && <button name='click' onClick={() => setState(state + 1)}>Click me</button>
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Main.test.js

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Main from "./Main";


describe("state", () => {
    test("state update or not", () => {
        render(<Main />);
        const btn = screen.getByRole('button', {
            name: "Click me",
            hidden: true
        });
        const span = screen.queryByTestId("state");
        expect(span).toHaveTextContent(0);
        fireEvent.click(btn);
        expect(span).toHaveTextContent(1);
    });

    it("component visibe or not", () => {
        render(<Main />);
        
    })
})
```

Comment: Trigger the event that calls `setIsShow` first.

Comment: How i can trigger that event because I am not using that state in any tag? it just a variable for now , how i can trigger ?

Comment: If you want to test if it's visible, you check for the content in the rendered result. See https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro

Comment: How would this component ever be shown, now that I'm looking at it. The state is internal, not passed as a prop, so what would ever set isShow to true? Is that the issue you're running in to? You shouldn't be testing a components internals - test the rendered stuff.